# requirejs throws a 404 trying to load a file from karma runner

Tags: javascript, requirejs, karma-runner

I am trying to load a test helper module using requirejs, but it fails even when it has been already loaded as a dependency at the start of karma run, and I can't figure out what's the problem, I always get

```
There is no timestamp for /base/spec/helpers/testHelpers!'
```

Tests run fine, inside them I require any module of the app without problem, it only fails when I require specifically something from spec folder.

I have checked all karma related questions and none of them apply to these case.

My karma.conf file:

```
module.exports = function (config) {
  'use strict';

  config.set({
    basePath: '',
    frameworks: ['jasmine', 'requirejs'],
    files: [
      'bootstrapTests.js',
      {
          pattern: 'app/**/*.js',
          included: false
      },
      {
          pattern: 'entities/**/*.js',
          included: false
      },
      {
          pattern: 'config/**/*.js',
          included: false
      },
      {
          pattern: 'libs/**/*.js',
          included: false
      },
      {
          pattern: 'spec/**/*Spec.js',
          included: false
      },
      {
          pattern: 'spec/helpers/**/*.js',
          included: false
      }
    ],
    exclude: [
        'bootstrap.js',
        'bootstrap.built.js'
    ],
    preprocessors: {
        'app/**/*.js': ['coverage'],
        'entities/**/*.js': ['coverage']
    },
    coverageReporter: {
        reporters: [
            {
                type: 'text-summary'
            }
        ]
    },
    reporters: ['progress', 'coverage'],
    port: 9876,
    colors: true,
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
    autoWatch: true,
    browsers: ['PhantomJS'],
    singleRun: false
  });
};
```

My bootstrapTests.js file:

```
var tests = [];

for (var file in window.__karma__.files) {
    if (window.__karma__.files.hasOwnProperty(file)) {
        // Add all spec files and helpers
        if (/spec\/.+.js$/.test(file)) {
            tests.push(file);
        }
    }
}

require.config({
    baseUrl: '/base',
    paths: {
        'backbone': 'libs/backbone',
        'marionette': 'libs/backbone.marionette',
        'jquery': 'libs/jquery-2.1.1',
        'json2': 'libs/json2',
        'underscore': 'libs/underscore',
        'twig': 'libs/twig',

        'editor': 'app/editor',
        'widgets': 'app/widgets',
        'menu': 'app/menu',

        'helpers': 'spec/helpers'
    },
    map: {
        '*': {
            'jquery': 'config/jquery/jqueryPrivate'
        },
        'config/jquery/jqueryPrivate': { 'jquery': 'jquery' }
    },
    deps: tests,

    callback: window.__karma__.start
});
```

so in my tests,

```
define([
    'app/app',
    'backbone',
    'editor/editorController',
    'editor/editorApp',
], function (
    myApp,
    Backbone,
    editorController
) {
    'use strict';

    describe('editorApp', function () {

    .....
```

works like a charm, but when I try

```
define([
    'app/common/routerUtilities',
    'backbone',
    'helpers/testHelpers'
], function (
    routerUtilities,
    Backbone,
    testHelpers
) {
    'use strict';

    describe('routerUtilities', function () {
    ...
```

it fails trying to fetch testHelpers, always get the error even when the module is already loaded. I tried specifying the path in all possible ways besides the shortened one: spec/helpers/testHelpers, /base/spec/helpers/testHelpers, /spec/helpers/testHelpers, ../../helpers/testHelpers, etc...

The file is included in tests array as a dependency (checked), so it's loaded (checked with console.log) along my tests and other test setup modules:

```
LOG: ['/base/spec/app/appSpec.js',
'/base/spec/app/common/routerUtilitiesSpec.js',
'/base/spec/app/editor/EditorLayoutViewSpec.js',
'/base/spec/app/editor/editorAppSpec.js',
'/base/spec/app/editor/editorControllerSpec.js',
'/base/spec/app/menu/menuControllerSpec.js',
'/base/spec/helpers/envSetup.js',
'/base/spec/helpers/testHelpers.js']
```

I've checked that is included in window._ *karma* _.files as well (edited for brevity):

```
LOG: Object{
 /base/bootstrapTests.js: 'c389a1d36d1c48f2879d434b10fd5a25b6b07758', 
 /base/app/app.js: '7ad39554809146effd20dd1db908fc068f8119ba',
 /base/app/common/routerUtilities.js: '4da0e1d1794cccc727b544cacbc6d672c0d9965a',
 ...
/base/config/marionette/renderer.js: '34a5e729f6133aa13841c5e949307cd437ca331b', 
/base/config/marionette/templateCache.js: '9f1901d4c6f43f5f90dadacb1c4ac179efd14b15', 
 /base/spec/app/appSpec.js: 'e01f4fea3533e25cfcd4f7621e1c1c5559e0eed8', 
/base/spec/app/common/routerUtilitiesSpec.js: 'a06b9793a635633d053142dff24d1ba4427dd365',
/base/spec/app/editor/EditorLayoutViewSpec.js: 'a24c7e8742e38b86d626bd6f3e45baacfa6af5eb', 
/base/spec/app/editor/editorAppSpec.js: '800c0e8e82840ebd0d1af07c3ec4556a24ee0b04', 
/base/spec/app/editor/editorControllerSpec.js: 'd2e259a477da85b6a2f742f5c6c3a4a34b7e340b', 
/base/spec/helpers/envSetup.js: '297aa1e59477d967aa210bece1726e8a372cb630', 
/base/spec/helpers/testHelpers.js: '5266065d344ca69f8f5980db16bf6d131492ebd0'
```

}

The content of spec/helpers/testHelpers.js is:

```
define([
    'backbone'
], function (
    Backbone
) {
    'use strict';

    var testHelpers = {
        setupRoutingTest: function () {
            Backbone.history.start();
            Backbone.history.navigate('');
        },
        teardownRoutingTest: function () {
            Backbone.history.navigate('');
            Backbone.history.stop();
        }
    };
    return testHelpers;
});
```

My folder structure is:

```
|-app

  |---common

  |---editor

  |---menu

  |---widgets

|-config

  |---jquery

  |---marionette

|-entities

|-features

|-gruntTasks

   |---lib

|-spec

   |---app

      |-----common

      |-----editor

      |-----menu

      |-----widgets

   |---entities

   |---helpers

 |-tmp
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hi it looks like the karma-requirejs doesn't like the resources to be loaded into the `tests` array.

Try to modify the code to exclude the helper files and it could help

```
var tests = [];

for (var file in window.__karma__.files) {
    if (window.__karma__.files.hasOwnProperty(file)) {
        // Add all spec files and helpers
        if (/spec\/.+.js$/.test(file)) {
            tests.push(file);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe it's me but I don't understand your answer :/ This code is the same as the one in `bootstrapTests.js` in the question?

Comment: @glepretre Sorry I didn't make it clear. If you look into the karma.conf file, you will find out the test files and the helper files are all in spec folder. If you put all files into `tests` array, they all will be treated as tests and might not be loaded as dependencies of the test.

Answer (score 1):

This drove me a little nuts a while back. Make sure you're using karma-requirejs, not just requirejs.

https://www.npmjs.org/package/karma-requirejs

On that note, don't also load the production version of requirejs.

Comment: I'm using karma-requirejs. I just added libs/require.js to karma.conf exclude section to make sure I'm not using any other version, but the error persists.

Comment: Have you tried removing all specs from the globbing? Then re-add them one-by-one. I've fixed some dependencies that way before.

Comment: As haochang posted, it seems that any file specified as an initial dependency can't be required later, excluding them from the tests array worked like a charm!